# How to generated Javadoc document in either English or Japanese from one source code

Tags: javadoc, doxygen

I'm developing software development kit for Android. 
For API reference document, I use Javadoc for Android SDK. 
Latest API document is Japanese only because all of our engineers are Japanese... 
English API document is old because it is not maintained from when translated once. 
Maintain generated Javadoc HTML is too hard for us.

Adding English comment to Japanese comment in source code is acceptable. 
So I'd like to switch generated document to English or Japanese by an option, such as "-locale". 
Could you please let me know how to realize it?

And I developing SDK for iOS and use Doxygen for iOS SDK API document. 
I also switch generated document language in Doxygen. 
Could you please let me know in Doxygen?

Comment: I don't see the real question regarding doxygen.

Comment: Sorry for lack of information. I also generate English or Japanese API document by using Doxygen from one source code. But I don't know how to switch comments which should be selected.

Comment: I think the commands \~... might give the required information, otherwise please show a small example off what you got / tried so far.

Comment: Oh!!! Your information, using commands "\~" (e.g. \~english, \~japanese) solve my problem!! Thank you!!!
I also look for same function in Javadoc. If you know, could you please let me know?

Comment: Sorry I don't know javadoc.